# Navigation border short but background color is fully highlighted

Tags: css

How to make the border line short but when hover the particular tab, the background color is fully highlighted? 
Thanks!

Image attached here:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6FwTbVhsVH9dkxPejZHYXhwU2M/view?usp=sharing
```

You may need to see what I did on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meigiemgg/gjjvpwru/).

Comment: any relevant code? what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Sai added jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is dude

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SzymonDziewonski/gjjvpwru/2/)

all you need is to do correct build of html
li is bigger then hover bg and  make with border

```
.navigation .nav li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 10px 0;
    font-size: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.navigation .nav li a{
    padding: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid #6b6b6b;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    
}
```

**NOTE**

`font-size: 0;` for nav and then for anchor `font-size: 14px;` is made because of of bug with `display: inline-block;` which is doing few pixels gap between elements. You could use of course `float: left;` but you did `inline-block` so I fix it

Comment: btw, why you put font-size: 0? i tried to remove it and it doesnt affect anything. :)

Comment: I've wrote why I put it, its bug, yeah on "li" it does not affect but when you remove from whole "nav.menu" you'll get gap between each element in this case when you hover for example first element it will be few pixels from second one (border-left) shows you where starts second